# Can I print the Visual Studio log in my xamarin app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, logging

I want to send the application logs from my xamarin application to a pc. While debugging if I write something to the console with `Console.WriteLine` it will show up in the visual studio console, but I found no possibility to access the logs on my device when not connected to a pc (I cannot write them to my own file, because I need the logs from third-party libraries).

Is there any possibility to get the logs from the device for the current session?

Additional information:

- Device: Galaxy Tab S2
- Android: v7.0

Answer (score 0):

See if this solves your problem

MatLog is a free and open-source material-style log reader for Android based on CatLog.

It shows a scrolling (tailed) view of the Android "logcat" system log, hence the goofy name. It also allows you to record logs in real time, send logs via email, and filter using a variety of criteria.

GitHub link
https://github.com/plusCubed/matlog

PlayStore link
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pluscubed.matlog